# Matlab : how to get M(1,2) from vector v=[1,2]?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, matrix-indexing

Say I have:

```
M = [1, 2; 3, 4]
v = [1, 2];
```

M(v) gives `[1 3]` but I want to get is `M(1, 2)` = 3.

Is there a way to do it? Of course, I could do `M(v(1), v(2))` but I need the thing to work for M an *N*-dimensional array and `v` a vector of length *N*.

Thanks very much

Comment: `M(1,2)` addresses the 2nd column of the 1st row of `M` which is `2`.  Why do you want that expression to return `3` ?  I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: note that `M(1,2)` is 2 in this case, 3 would be `M(2,1)`

Comment: Sorry it was M(1,2)=2. I found the answer to my question in the topic proposed by Eitan : V=num2cell(v) and then M(V{:}). Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to get values from M, I would use
    M(sub2ind(size(M),v(:,1),v(:,2)))
this will work for vector version of v nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You could use how Matlab expands `cell`

```
M = [1, 2; 3, 4]
v = {1, 2}
M( v{:} )
```

( you can transform v with `v_cell=num2cell(v)` )